# DaVinci resolve undeletable folders

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I have DaVinci resolve, and I need to move my workspace folder. Unfortunately, there are 3 folders called:
sanc.
s888.
s7b4.
s3ho.
that I cannot copy, move, deleted, or interact with at all. in the properties it says that they are all 0 bytes.
[image]
[image]
just moving the work space may fix it, but I don't know how to do that.
I cant just leave it there either, because it is on my desktop, and I hate cluttered desktops.
any help would be helpfull, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running chkdsk /f

Comment: Have you restarted?

Comment: I have tried both, still nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem, di you solve it?

Comment: @TTT I have posted an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

open cmd (win + r, type cmd, press enter), type:

```
cd (path to parent directory)
dir /x
```

this will output all the files and folders in the directory, and next to the name will be the folders shortname. eg:

```
                                          |
                                         \_/
04/09/2016  07:17 AM    <DIR>          RTGHGR~1     rtghgrfdfv
```

now type:

```
rmdir /s (shortname)
```

this should remove the directory.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted this but this doesn't seem to work on Win10. Looks like the shortname column is empty.

Comment: it works fine for me, but files and some folders don't have short names for some reason.